# How can I close the browser when program is killed accidentally in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I had a test script with `Selenium RC`. Now I don't know what could happen during the test but I want the browser to be shut down if the program is killed accidentally. BTW, the script is running in a sub-process.

Now I tried method `__del__` but it doesn't work and I don't see if there's any exceptions. So I have no idea where to put `try --- except` or `with --- in`.

If I run the script in main-process it works fine. Any help?

Version of `Selenium` is 2.33. Browser is `Firefox` 21.0

Answer (score 0):

make the **del** method return boolean.
True on success, false otherwise.

If it returns false, close the driver in main.

Comment: thanks for your anwser.First. how could i get the __del__ result in main?Second. how can i close the driver in main?cause the object instance is only alive in sub

Comment: You can get a return value from a function. If you don't know how to do it, search for it. If the driver is not in main, write a function to close the driver say __close__ and call it.